# Tkinter: can I bind with arguments?

Tags: events, tkinter, bind, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a map program with tkinter but I'm having trouble creating icons which display information when clicked, or when the mouse passes over them.

```
root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.geometry("500x500")

def text_map_icon(canvas, origin_x, origin_y, text):
    canvas.create_text(origin_x, origin_y - 60, text=text)


def map_icon(canvas, origin_x, origin_y, text):
    icon = canvas.create_arc((origin_x - 50), (origin_x - 50), (origin_y + 50), (origin_y + 50), start=70, extent=40,
                             fill='green', activefill='red', activewidth=2.0)

    canvas.tag_bind(icon, '<Enter>', text_map_icon(c, origin_x, origin_y, text))

map_icon(c, 250, 250, 'map icon')

c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To do this I have created a map icon with the create_arc canvas method. In order to display information upon clicking the icon, I have tried to bind it to the text_map_icon function. In order for that text to display the relevant information on the map (which can change depending on the data fed to it), I need that function to have arguments for the text and coordinates.

I understand that normally when binding functions the argument of the function is 'event', and when called no arguments are given. Is there a way to bind a function with arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.geometry("500x500")

c = Canvas(root)

def text_map_icon(event, canvas, origin_x, origin_y, text):
    canvas.create_text(origin_x, origin_y - 60, text=text)

def map_icon(canvas, origin_x, origin_y, text):
    icon = canvas.create_arc((origin_x - 50), (origin_x - 50), (origin_y + 50), (origin_y + 50), start=70, extent=40,
                             fill='green', activefill='red', activewidth=2.0)

    canvas.tag_bind(icon, '<Enter>', lambda e: text_map_icon(e, c, origin_x, origin_y, text))

map_icon(c, 250, 250, 'map icon')

c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's worked. I tried to use lambda before but i think i missed out the e before the colon.